# jQuery select the div only which is inside clicked div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a plugin which has following configuration:

```
$('.colorSelector').ColorPicker({   
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {    
        $('.colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
```

So on change, it will add css to a `div` which is inside the `.colorSelector` class. I have multiple `.colorSelector` classes, so I want that it adds the css to the only that `.coloSelector div` which is clicked, not all of them.

So I am trying to change:

```
$('.colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
```

to:

```
$(this).find('div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
```

This does not seem to work. How can I select the div which is only in side the `.colorSelector` which is clicked.

Edit: It seems that the problem is caused because of dynamically appending the colorSelector div on the page. If it already exists, then it works.

Comment: What you are trying to do should work. Care to create a fiddle?

Comment: Thanks, i figured out. Its because of dynamically appending the `colorSelector` div on the page. If it already exists then it would work.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently mixing JavaScript and CSS notation - it would be

```
 .css("background-color",...)
```

If you are using [jQuery UI color picker](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#colorpicker), you can do this -

```
function refreshSwatch(e) {
  ...

  $(e.target).parent().css("background-color","#"+hex);
}
```

No matter which colorpicker you use the code would likely be applicable